# Convert Javascript Array to JSON

Tags: php, json

I think this will be marked as duplicate but i'm unable to understand my problem.

I created javascript array using in loop resulting array in console is

```
["about.png", "about1.png", "about2.png"]
```

I want to pass this to php so i converted it to json string using `JSON.stringify(filenames);` I also included json2.js but result is same in console before decoding it..

```
["about.png","about1.png","about2.png"]
```

than I decode it `$filenames = json_decode($_POST['jsonfilenames']);` but file names array is empty. What I'm doing wrong?

I will be able to get javascript array in php as php array that's what JSON.stringify does?

**Update**

I'm using uploadify to upload files to get filenames and filepaths I thought of creating array of filenames and filepaths and onAllComplete function pass these array to php scirpt...than will email to user who uploaded the files having filename and filepaths in email....

```
var filenames = [];
var filepaths = [];

$('#file_upload').uploadify({
  'uploader'  : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'script'    : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
  'cancelImg' : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
  'folder'    : 'user_data/<?=$_SESSION['username']?>',
  'auto'      : false,
  'multi'       :true,
  'onComplete' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

     filenames.push(fileObj.name);
     filepaths.push(fileObj.filePath);

  },
  'onAllComplete':function(event,data) {

    console.log(filenames); 

    var jsonfilenames = JSON.stringify(filenames);
    var jsonfilepaths = JSON.stringify(filepaths);
    console.log(jsonfilenames); 

    //ajax stuff    
  },
  //...
});
```

Comment: Have you seen what is actually being posted before trying to use `json_decode()` on it? (ie: `print $_POST['jsonfilenames']`)

Comment: Thanks @nulluserexception i got this [\"Screenshot.png\",\"Screenshot-1.png\"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is probably being corrupted by [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).
To "solve" this you can use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), ie:

```
$filenames = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonfilenames']));
```

But since magic quotes is a deprecated feature, you should disable it.

Comment: how these are added quotes and slashes ? by using JSON.stringify ? after using stripslashes still i'm getting the same output...and strange its concatenating with previous result....[\"Screenshot.png\",\"Screenshot-1.png\",\"Screen shot 2010-10-05 at 10.12.42 AM.png\",\"Screenshot.png\",\"Screenshot.png\",\"Screenshot-1.png\"]

Comment: @Yasir I presume PHP is adding the quotes, but then, you can find out what's actually being sent by using something like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/).

Comment: huhh it works!!! but still i'm not getting why quotes and slashes added thanks for suggesting live http headers installing now... Thank you so much for help :)